# Where can I configure DCC_ExeOutput?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Is it possible to configure `DCC_ExeOutput` from Delphi? I could only change this by editing the `dproj` file.

I couldn't find where to edit this option even using Delphi IDE Insight.

### Update 1:

This is my Project Options:

[image]

@TOndrej have suggested me change `output directory`, but I have already done this, and DCC_ExecOutput didn't change. The only way was editing `dproj` file.

### Update 2:

My purpose is organize the folder structure of Delphi projects like suggested by Zarco Gajic in his article [How to Layout Delphi Project Files - Best Practice](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/project_layout.htm).
Delphi creates folders for each platform to store `.dcu`, `.exe` and other files. `.\$(Platform)\$(Config)` is the default for Delphi. So in the same level of `.dproj` Delphi creates the folders `Win32`, `Win64`, `Android`, etc.
As you can see in the picture above, I've configured Delphi to put those files in a better organized form, in my opinion. Below an example:

```
My_Delphi_Project_folder
    Bin
    |___Debug
    |   |____Win32
    |   |____Win64
    |   |____Android
    |___Release
        |____Win32
        |____Win64
        |____Android
```

But after compile, the resulted structure was like below:

```
My_Delphi_Project_folder
    Win32
    Win64
    Android
    Bin
    |___Debug
    |   |____Win32
    |   |____Win64
    |   |____Android
    |___Release
        |____Win32
        |____Win64
        |____Android
```

After investigating `.dproj` file I found the guilty. It was `DCC_ExeOutput`.

As I didn't find a way to configures it in Delphi, I asked for help here.
It has a long time that I don't work with Delphi, and I thought that could be a very simple thing that I have passed up. That's the cause of lack of information in my question.

Comment: Check the settings for your specific target (example : 32 bits - Debug)

Comment: I'm thinking that it is a bug. I have just tested and this only occurs when I create a package.

Comment: Probably because a package doesn't end in an EXE file but rather in a BPL file. Have a look into the "Package output directory".

Comment: Not sure why the close votes, seems a valid question to me, with effort and research put into it.

Comment: @DavidM There are no close votes

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Typo (still drinking my day-start coffee.) Downvotes. It was at -2 some time ago.

Comment: @DavidM What I don't really understand here is what more Daniel could be looking for

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I put more information, and I hope now my question is clearer.

Comment: Your question was clear before and surely it has been answered.

Comment: It's interesting though that the compiler still creates those directories even when nothing is going to go in them. A little bit of a glitch. At least you know how to deal with the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important information here is the type of project. Your project is a package. As such the `DCC_ExeOutput` setting is not relevant. It has no impact on the build process. What matters for a package is the `DCC_BplOutput` setting. The IDE still appears to emit to the .dproj file a value for the `DCC_ExeOutput` setting, but this value is ignored, and can be removed from the .dproj file.

**Package projects**

- Main source file begins with `package`.
- The output location for the package is determined by the `DCC_BplOutput` node in the .dproj file.
- In the IDE this setting corresponds to the *Package output directory* option in the project options dialog.
- The IDE's new package dialog produces a .dproj file that contains a `DCC_ExeOutput` node. This node is ignored and can safely be removed from the .dproj file. There is no option in the IDE that corresponds to the `DCC_ExeOutput` node in a package .dproj file.

**Executable and library projects**

- Main source file begins with `program` or `library`.
- The output location for the project is determined by the `DCC_ExeOutput` node in the .dproj file.
- In the IDE this setting corresponds to the *Output directory* option in the project options dialog.

Comment: **Not exactly ignored...** For Windows target platforms there are generated empty directories during compilation.
But for Android target platform auto-generated HPP files are stored on this path.

IMHO it's really strange that this setting is hidden in project options for packages...

Answer (score 3):

See "Output Directory" in [Project Options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Delphi_Compiler).

Comment: This option was still edited in my config, but DCC_ExecOutput didn't change.

Comment: +1, default value for `Ouput Directory` is `.\$(Platform)\$(Config)` (in my case it's cleared by unknown reason)